# Are moderators paid to moderate?

Tags: discussion

If not why would they devote so much time editing questions and so forth?

What do they get in return for these services?

Answer (score 13):

**Paid?** No.

**What do I get?** Well, aside from the thrill of power there is the warm glow of a job well done and they sent me a Stack Exchange Tee-shirt so that all may know me for the geek I am.

---

**Update Dec, 2012** StackExchange is [making charitable donations in the names of community moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/stack-exchange-gives-back-2011/), which feels like a kind of compensation to me

Comment: seems like stack exchanges in general provide a useful service to people... I don't see why a useful service should be provided for free if it takes up a qualified person's time. I guess stackoverflow.com is not gonna introduce a premium subscriber option--- as it sort of goes against what this movement is all about--- free flow of ideas

Comment: I figure it as an extension of the duties that are expected (but not enforced) of a high rep user. Check out [the privileges page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges) to see what sort of cool tool can be yours with enough effort.

Comment: @Timtam: I can't find the reference right now, but I'm pretty sure the idea of a premium subscriber option was raised (and immediately denied by the people in charge) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Once Stackexchange starts to get revenue some way, the moderators will need to be paid. I can't see stackexchange becmoning another Wikipedia

Comment: Note that Stackexchange is 'addictive' because answering questions is more attractive than learning difficult concepts (deliberate practice).

Answer (score 8):

[image: absolute power corrupts absolutely, but it also rocks absolutely.]

(But seriously, remember that community moderators [are democratically elected](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election). See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/ for details on that. So you might well ask, "why does anyone run for public office?")

Comment: i'm pretty sure public office jobs come with a salary and cushy benefits

Comment: yes, but for the cushy benefits, see above image.

Comment: ooh, does this mean we get to shoot lightning out of our hands?

Comment: Power wears out those who don't have it ;-)

Comment: Members of school boards often aren't paid :P